# Using multiple layers of quotes in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script, and I'm running into a quoting problem.

The end result I'm after is for my script to call:

```
lwp-request -U -e -H "Range: bytes=20-30"
```

My script file looks like:

```
CLIENT=lwp-request
REQ_HDRS=-U
RSP_HDRS=-e
RANGE="-H "Range: bytes=20-30""   # Obviously can't do nested quotes here
${CLIENT} ${REQ_HDRS} ${RSP_HDRS} ${RANGE}
```

I know I can't use nested-quotes.  But how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Normally, you could escape the inner quotes with `\`:

```
RANGE="-H \"Range: bytes=20-30\""
```

But this won't work when running a command – unless you put `eval` before the whole thing:

```
RANGE="-H \"Range: bytes=20-30\""
eval $CLIENT $REQ_HDRS $RSP_HDRS $RANGE
```

However, since you're using bash, not *sh*, you can put separate arguments in arrays:

```
RANGE=(-H "Range: bytes=20-30")
$CLIENT $REQ_HDRS $RSP_HDRS "${RANGE[@]}"
```

This can be extended to:

```
ARGS=(
    -U                             # Request headers
    -e                             # Response headers
    -H "Range: bytes=20-30"        # Range
)
$CLIENT "${ARGS[@]}"
```

Comment: Backslash escaping and using `eval` fixed it for me.  Thanks!  I'll look into converting to an array of arguments later.

Comment: @abelenky: please don't use `eval`, it's full of traps for the unwary.  The array approach is far more reliable.

Comment: How can you debug this if this still won't work? How is `$ARGS` supposed to look if you just `echo` it in this example?

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru: You're _not_ supposed to echo `$ARGS` in the first place, as it would only access the first element of the array (which is `-U` in this case) (not to mention confusing the 'echo' command if the arg happens to be -e or -n) – only `${ARGS[@]}` would give you all elements. However, due to echo being echo, it would just glue them together with spaces, and still wouldn't tell you anything about *which* arg is what. Instead, you should use `typeset -p ARGS` to inspect a bash variable, or something like `for x in ${!ARGS[@]}; do echo "arg $x = ${ARGS[x]}"; done`.

Comment: Well, that's what I meant, sorry: just for debugging, what is inside the array? `echo "${ARGS[@]}"` Are you supposed to see the quotes? Because I'm trying to pass a video filename with spaces to `ffmpeg` and this doesn't work (since recently). — Okay good, I see the quotes with `typeset` while I don't with the `echo` loop.

Comment: @WoodrowShigeru: "are you supposed to see the quotes" yes with typeset, no with echo. The quotes are part of the shell syntax – but they are not part of the variable's _contents_, and they are not supposed to be part of the actual argument either. (Whichever debugging tool you use, it's important to distinguish where the value begins and ends in the output.)

Comment: Never mind my comments: this only still didn't work for my `ffmpeg` case because the output dir wasn't quoted – a line totally unrelated to this array.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

> RANGE='\"-H \"Range: bytes=20-30\"\"

you can espape using '' and \"

> no_error=''errors=\"0\"'';

Comment: What did you search to find a 6 year old question!?

Comment: "bash three levels of quotes" in Google. This is the top answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that both '' and "" can be used for strings.
So you can do things like this:

```
x='Say "hi"'
y="What's up?"
```

Comment: This will work to create a string that contains quotes. However, it won't work if you are trying to pass it to a command. Using an array as per [grawity's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8757164/1862009) is what worked for me.